# How do I wait until my lambda function finishes processing an SQS queue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I add a bunch of s3 paths to SQS, and lambda automatically triggers based off the SQS queue. How would I trigger a job to run only after the queue is empty?

This seems like a challenge because if I set it to trigger when the queue is empty, it will infinitely trigger before the job runs. If I set it to trigger if the current value is 0 and the former value is non-zero, I could have it trigger accidentally before the full job is done if it processes the first few entries really fast.

How would I set a callback to run a lambda for when an sqs recently reached 0 entries after processing data?

Comment: Could you please describe for us _why_ you wish to trigger a Lambda function when the queue is empty? This is not a usual requirement for loosely-coupled systems. It is also difficult because the queue might appear "empty" even while a Lambda function is processing a message.

Comment: For GDPR compliance we have a step function. The step function is made to process all files in an s3 bucket and then move on only after that step is complete. The first step is lambda that  recursively scans s3 bucket and sends all paths to SQS. A lambda executes for each SQS message modifying the original s3 file. 

Having a way to temporarily add a run-once trigger after adding the s3 paths, for when the sqs count is 0 would allow the step function to detect when the job is done and move on.

Comment: Do you _really_ need to wait? What is the business requirement for actually waiting, rather than passing data to the other function, knowing that it will execute. Will something be processed incorrect if it does not wait? If you want to be 100% sure, you might rearchitect it so that the Step Function directly triggers the Lambda functions rather than using a queue. This way, it would be managed rather than loosely-coupled.

Comment: After SQS is empty, the next lambda does a check for lambda errors and any dead letter items that weren't processed successfully. If any unit tests fail it emails me for manual intervention. If it succeeds it would email someone else to notify them the compliance task was completed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"if the current value is 0 and the former value is non-zero" - Confirm the list is empty when you check for this sequence